# jQuery elevateZoom, how to close the lens when the mouse reaches the corner

Tags: jquery

So, I have an image, which can be zoomed using elevateZoom (jQuery plugin). Nearby this image there are several links.

When the user is zooming the image, and he moves to the corner of the image to click one of those links, he is unable to do it. In fact, even when the mouse pointer is outside the image, the lens is still active, and (although links are visible) it does not let the user to click the links (because the links are above the lens, of course).

Here a practical example:
http://jsfiddle.net/18mubj8f/

I wonder if there is a jQuery-ish way, so that, when the mouse reaches the corner, the lens will close automatically.

Of course I am triyng to do it, but I am finding some really weird behaviour:

- If I let jQuery compute the outerHeight, then the lens automatically closes when the mousepointer goes out from the image (so the mouse reaches the corner of the `#zoom_me image`): http://jsfiddle.net/dhhf3ob3/1/
- If I do not compute this quantiy, then the lens does not closes when the mouse reaches the corner of the image: http://jsfiddle.net/dhhf3ob3/2/

Comment: Well constructed question, samples and 3 fiddles and everything. Your first option seems fine to me although I'm not sure what the answer is.

Comment: The first option is absolutely not jQuery-ish (IMHO), since I just call `parent.outerHeight()` on mouseover and this let it works. And I find no sense in it

Comment: It works, so go with it. Worry about it if there's a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `outerHeight()` behaviour affects only Firefox (I have tried it in the 31.1.0).

I have solved attaching an event `mouseevent` on the `zoomLens` div.

Noteworthy, I can't just call `parent.css('display','none')` when the mouse pointer reaches the corner. I had to call it within a callback in the `setTimeout`. Here is a working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/hxqrjL45/